# How to combine Multiple Maps with multiple same keys and lists as values?

Tags: java, lambda, collections, stream, hashmap

I am new to Java and I am trying to merge multiple maps with string as key and list as values to produce a new Map.

```java
public class Student {
    private String name;
    private String country;

    //Setters and Getters
}
```

Now I have an util class to add students to the list based on their country.

```java
public class MapAdder {
    static Map<String, List<Student>> studentMap =
            new LinkedHashMap<String, List<Student>>();

    public static void addToMap(String key, Student student) {
        studentMap.computeIfAbsent(key,
                k -> new LinkedList<Student>()).add(student);
    }

    public static Map<String, List<Student>> getStudentMap() {
        return studentMap;
    }

    public static void clearStudentMap() {
        studentMap.clear();
    }
}
```

Main Method

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, List<Student>> studentMap1;
    Map<String, List<Student>> studentMap2;
    Map<String, List<Student>> studentMap3;

    MapAdder.addToMap("India", new Student("Mounish", "India"));
    MapAdder.addToMap("USA", new Student("Zen", "USA"));
    MapAdder.addToMap("India", new Student("Ram", "India"));
    MapAdder.addToMap("USA", new Student("Ronon", "USA"));
    MapAdder.addToMap("UK", new Student("Tony", "UK"));

    studentMap1 = MapAdder.getStudentMap();
    MapAdder.clearStudentMap();

    MapAdder.addToMap("India", new Student("Rivar", "India"));
    MapAdder.addToMap("UK", new Student("Loki", "UK"));
    MapAdder.addToMap("UK", new Student("Imran", "UK"));
    MapAdder.addToMap("USA", new Student("ryan", "USA"));

    studentMap2 = MapAdder.getStudentMap();
    MapAdder.clearStudentMap();

    Map<String, List<Student>> map3 = Stream.of(studentMap1, studentMap2)
            .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Entry::getKey,
                    Entry::getValue
            ));
}
```

But when I try to merge both the maps I am getting empty map.
Actually, I need to have a map with three keys (India, UK, USA) and their values that are list from multiple maps to be merged w.r.t keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove from your code the following calls:

```java
MapAdder.clearStudentMap();
```

you are clearing the `studentMap1` and `studentMap2`.

When you do:

```java
studentMap1 = MapAdder.getStudentMap();
```

you get the memory reference in which the student `Map` is stored. When you call the `clear` method on that map

```java
studentMap.clear();
```

you will clear all the `Map` entries stored on that same memory reference. In other words, the following statement

```java
studentMap1 = MapAdder.getStudentMap();
```

does not create a copy of the student `Map`, instead it just saves on the variable `studentMap1` the memory reference to that Map.

Your Stream method is *almost* right, change it to:

```java
Map<String, List<Student>> map3 = Stream.of(studentMap1, studentMap2)
        .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                Map.Entry::getKey,
                e -> new ArrayList<>(e.getValue()),
                (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; }
        ));
```

You need also to add the strategy to be used to deal with the duplicate keys (*i.e.,* the `mergeFunction` parameter of the `Collectors.toMap` method). In case of duplicated keys we add the Map values into the list of the *left* key.

Btw drop some of those helper methods IMO they obfuscate the code, and make the `addToMap` method more *generic* by passing the `Map` itself as parameter, so that you can reuse that method with different mappers, namely:

```java
public class MapAdder {
    public static void addToMap(Map<String, List<Student>> studentMap,
                                String key, Student student) {
        studentMap.computeIfAbsent(key,
                k -> new LinkedList<Student>()).add(student);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<Student>> studentMap1 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<String, List<Student>> studentMap2 = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        Map<String, List<Student>> studentMap3;

        MapAdder.addToMap(studentMap1, "India", new Student("Mounish", "India"));
        MapAdder.addToMap(studentMap1, "USA", new Student("Zen", "USA"));
        MapAdder.addToMap(studentMap1, "India", new Student("Ram", "India"));
        MapAdder.addToMap(studentMap1, "USA", new Student("Ronon", "USA"));
        MapAdder.addToMap(studentMap1, "UK", new Student("Tony", "UK"));

        MapAdder.addToMap(studentMap2, "India", new Student("Rivar", "India"));
        MapAdder.addToMap(studentMap2, "UK", new Student("Loki", "UK"));
        MapAdder.addToMap(studentMap2, "UK", new Student("Imran", "UK"));
        MapAdder.addToMap(studentMap2, "USA", new Student("ryan", "USA"));

        Map<String, List<Student>> map3 = Stream.of(studentMap1, studentMap2)
                .flatMap(map -> map.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        e -> new ArrayList<>(e.getValue()),
                        (left, right) -> { left.addAll(right); return left; }
                ));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you keep clearing the shared list.  Independent lists need to be created.

But there is a much easier way to add the values than to use your `MapAdder` class.  Remember that the `country` is also part of the student class.  So just extract that and create the map using streams.

Now create studentMap1

```
List<Student> list1 = List.of(
new Student("Mounish", "India"),
new Student("Zen", "USA"),
new Student("Ram", "India"),
new Student("Ronon", "USA"),
new Student("Tony", "UK"));
Map<String, List<Student>> studentMap1 = 
     list1.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getCountry));

studentMap1.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
USA=[{Zen,  USA}, {Ronon,  USA}]
UK=[{Tony,  UK}]
India=[{Mounish,  India}, {Ram,  India}]
```

Now create studentMap2

```
List<Student> list2 = List.of(
new Student("Rivar", "India"),
new Student("Loki", "UK"),
new Student("Imran", "UK"),
new Student("ryan", "USA"));
Map<String, List<Student>> studentMap2 = 
   list2.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getCountry));

studentMap2.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
USA=[{ryan,  USA}]
UK=[{Loki,  UK}, {Imran,  UK}]
India=[{Rivar,  India}]
```

Now that you have the maps, you can create the combined map the same way.  Just use the values of each map and then stream them to get the student instances.

```
Map<String, List<Student>> map3 = Stream.of(studentMap1,studentMap2)
        .map(Map::values)               // values which is a collection of lists
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)    // flat map the two collections
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)    // flat map the lists to just
                                        // a stream of students
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getCountry));

map3.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
USA=[{Zen,  USA}, {Ronon,  USA}, {ryan,  USA}]
UK=[{Tony,  UK}, {Loki,  UK}, {Imran,  UK}]
India=[{Mounish,  India}, {Ram,  India}, {Rivar,  India}]
```

You were fortunate that the Map key was included as part of the Student class.  But let's assume that the key was independent of the class.  Then you could use your `mapAdder` to build the original maps.  And the final map could be created using the following with a `merge` function for merging duplicate keys.

```
Map<String, List<Student>> map4 =
   Stream.of(studentMap1, studentMap2)
        .flatMap(m -> m.entrySet().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey,
            e -> new ArrayList<>(e.getValue),
           (lst1, lst2) -> {lst1.addAll(lst2); return lst1;}));
```

The student class with getters and setters and toString

```
class Student {
    private String name;
    private String country;
    
    public Student(String name, String country) {
        this.name = name;
        this.country = country;
    }
    
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    
    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("{%s,  %s}", name, country);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When creating a [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instance, you can override its [`put`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K,%20V)) and [`putAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#putAll(java.util.Map)) methods, so that they don't replace existing values, but append them, i.e. merge lists of values for the same keys:

```java
Map<String, List<Student>> studentMap = new HashMap<>() {
    @Override
    public List<Student> put(String key, List<Student> value) {
        if (this.containsKey(key)) {
            List<Student> val = this.get(key);
            val.addAll(value);
            return val;
        } else {
            return super.put(key, new ArrayList<>(value));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void putAll(Map<? extends String, ? extends List<Student>> m) {
        Iterator<? extends Entry<? extends String, ? extends List<Student>>>
                iterator = m.entrySet().iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Entry<? extends String, ? extends List<Test.Student>>
                    e = iterator.next();
            this.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
        }
    }
};
```

```java
studentMap.put("India", List.of(new Student("Mounish", "India")));
studentMap.put("USA", List.of(new Student("Zen", "USA")));

studentMap.putAll(Map.of(
        "India", List.of(new Student("Ram", "India")),
        "USA", List.of(new Student("Ronon", "USA")),
        "UK", List.of(new Student("Tony", "UK"))));

studentMap.putAll(Map.of(
        "India", List.of(new Student("Rivar", "India")),
        "UK", List.of(new Student("Loki", "UK"))));

studentMap.putAll(Map.of(
        "UK", List.of(new Student("Imran", "UK")),
        "USA", List.of(new Student("ryan", "USA"))));
```

```java
studentMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + "=" + v));
// USA=[Zen:USA, Ronon:USA, ryan:USA]
// UK=[Tony:UK, Loki:UK, Imran:UK]
// India=[Mounish:India, Ram:India, Rivar:India]
```

If you don't need any more this extended functionality, you can drop it and return to the regular map:

```java
studentMap = new HashMap<>(studentMap);
```

---

<sup>See also: [The 'contains' method does not work for ArrayList<int[]>, is there another way?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65524025/14838237)</sup>