# The 'contains' method does not work for ArrayList<int[]>, is there another way?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, contains

I want to add an `int[]` to an ArrayList if it doesn't already have that `int[]`, but for some reason, it's not working. In this case, arrlist is the `ArrayList<int[]>` and arr is the `int[]`. This code is in a for loop where arr is defined in the loop, so the values in arr changes. Even though I printed out arrlist and it had arr, the code would always say that arrlist didn't contain arr. Is there another way to check if an ArrayList contains an `int[]`?

```java
int n = scan.nextInt();
ArrayList<int[]> arrlist = new ArrayList<>();
int[][] coordinates = new int[n][2];
boolean[] isTrue = new boolean[n];
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    int[] arr = new int[2];
    arr[0] = coordinates[j][0];
    arr[1] = coordinates[j][1];
    if (arrlist.contains(arr)) {
        isTrue[j] = true;
    } else {
        arrlist.add(arr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code:

```java
int[] a = {1, 2};
int[] b = {1, 2};
System.out.println(a.equals(b));
```

Do you understand why the output is "false"?

This is the cause of your problems: two arrays with equal content are not equal according to the 'equals' method, which is explicitly invoked here, and implicitly invoked in your `List<>` example.

I don't see an easy fix as long as you want to use `int[]` arrays.  You cannot define an equals method.  Your best approach, I think, is to not use an array at all to contain the coordinates.

Define a class whose instances hold the required two integers:

```java
class Point {
    int x, y;

    Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Point
                && x == ((Point) o).x
                && y == ((Point) o).y;
    }
}
```

and then keep an `ArrayList<Point>`. 'contains' will now work as expected.

(You should also define hashCode in class Point, but I skipped that, it is not immediately relevant to the answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since arrays don't compare on a per element basis you can't use contains as implemented by `ArrayList`.  You can use the `Arrays` class to do it as follows.  Create a helper method that takes the `List` and the array to check.  Remember that arrays are not like sets, so equality depends on order.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = scan.nextInt();
    List<int[]> arrlist = new ArrayList<>();
    int[][] coordinates = new int[n][2];
    boolean[] isTrue = new boolean[n];
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        int[] arr = new int[2];
        arr[0] = coordinates[j][0];
        arr[1] = coordinates[j][1];
        if (contains(arrlist,arr)) {
            isTrue[j] = true;
        } else {
            arrlist.add(arr);
        }
    }
}
private static boolean contains(List<int[]> list, int[] b) {
    for (int[] a : list) {
        if (Arrays.equals(a,b)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You could always just use a `List<List<Integer>>` instead of a `List<int[]>` since it is pretty much understood that arrays don't play well with lists.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, when creating an [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instance, you can *override* its [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method with a custom one, which compares the *contents* of two arrays instead of comparing the *references* of two array objects. This code should work on `Java 7`:

```java
int[] a = {1, 2};
int[] b = {1, 2};

ArrayList<int[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>() {
    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object that) {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.size(); i++)
            if (Arrays.equals(this.get(i), (int[]) that))
                return true;
        return false;
    }
};

arrayList.add(a);
System.out.println(arrayList.size());      // 1
System.out.println(arrayList.contains(a)); // true
System.out.println(arrayList.contains(b)); // true
```

---

You can use [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) instead of [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) with a comparator that compares the contents of two arrays. Then you can use [`TreeSet.contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) method as follows:

```java
TreeSet<int[]> treeSet = new TreeSet<>(Arrays::compare);

treeSet.add(new int[]{1, 2});
treeSet.add(new int[]{1, 2});
treeSet.add(new int[]{1, 3});

System.out.println(treeSet.size());                    // 2
System.out.println(treeSet.contains(new int[]{1, 2})); // true
System.out.println(treeSet.contains(new int[]{1, 3})); // true
```

```java
treeSet.stream().map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
// [1, 2]
// [1, 3]
```

---

<sup>See also:

• [Check if an array exists in a HashSet<int[]>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65463604/14838237)

• [How to make two arrays having different references?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65504260/14838237)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare each int-value in `arr` against the corresponding int-values of all arrays contained in Your `ArrayList arrlist`.
The shortest solution should be the following lambda:

`boolean contains = arrlist.stream().anyMatch( a -> arr[0] == a[0] && arr[1] == a[1] );`

`anyMatch` *stopps as soon as the first match is found*

Answer (score -2):

try this:

```
if(arrlist.indexOf(arr)!=-1){
   isTrue[j] = true;
}
```

I think there might be something funky going on with the .contains method when checking if an array object is in the list.

Comment: That's going to fail in the same way as the OP's code. for the same reason.   If you read the documentation of **contains** and **indexOf**, they both are defined in terms of the result of **equals**.